# Is it possible to have a permanent image set on top of a slideshow

Tags: html, css, image

Here is the slideshow element.

```
<div id="slideshow">

            <img src="<?echo $image1; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
            <img src="<?echo $image2; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
            <img src="<?echo $image3; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
            <img src="<?echo $image4; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
            <img src="<?echo $image5; ?>" alt="" class="active" />

 </div>
```

I want to add in a `<div id="business_logo">` that sits on top of this JS slideshow. Is there something I can do with z-index? Or is that redeundant when it comes to the slideshow...

The idea being that sit is a logo for a company sitting on top of a slideshow of their company images...

Comment: We need to see more code to be able to tell how your slideshow works and provide a solution from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```css
#slideshow {position: relative;}
.sticky-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  
  <div class="sticky-logo">IMAGE HERE</div>

            <img src="<?echo $image1; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
            <img src="<?echo $image2; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
            <img src="<?echo $image3; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
            <img src="<?echo $image4; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
            <img src="<?echo $image5; ?>" alt="" class="active" />

 </div>
```

Comment: I would not place the `sticky-logo` inside the `#slideshow` as the slider may see that as a slide.

Comment: From his code above I would presume that the code is looking for images.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="slideshowContainer">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="<?echo $image1; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
        <img src="<?echo $image2; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
        <img src="<?echo $image3; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
        <img src="<?echo $image4; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
        <img src="<?echo $image5; ?>" alt="" class="active" />
    </div>
    <div id="slideshowLogo"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshowContainer {position: relative;}
#sslideshowLogo {position: absolute; top: 15px; right: 15px;}
```

This keeps your slideshow structure intact so your script won't need changing.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
#business-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="business-logo">My Logo</div>

  <div id="slideshow">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200/" alt="" class="active" />

  </div>

</div>
```